# c print from a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to store ints in a pointer, using it like an array. But the following code produces small matrices in the terminal, which I do not know why. Here is my code

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char pointer[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        *(pointer+i) = 2;
    }

    printf("%s%d\n", "the string length is ",strlen(pointer));
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", *(pointer+j));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me what the problem is, and the solution please?
Thanks

Comment: `char pointer[7]` is an _array_, not a pointer! Its first element is, but not the array

Comment: can you post your output please?

Comment: "produces small matrices in the terminal" ? What is that supposed to be? Generally, it is not clear at all to me what you want to achieve. Why do you use `*(pointer+i)` instead of the easier to read `pointer[i]`? Perhaps *you* could tell us first what the problem is?

Comment: @JensGustedt The small matrices is probably his terminal's representation of `\x02`.

Comment: "*Its first element is, but not the array *" No, its 1st element is a `char` as all other six elementare as well.

Comment: Why are you using `*(pointer + i)` over `pointer[i]`?  That just makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you mean the following:)

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char pointer[7] = { '\0' };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        *(pointer+i) = '2';
    }

    printf("%s%zu\n", "the string length is ",strlen(pointer));
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", *(pointer+j));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After this statement

```
    char pointer[7] = { '\0' };
```

all elements of array pointer are initialized by zero. So you may use standard function `strlen` applied to this array.

Function `strlen` has return type `size_t` so it is better to use format string `%zu`

In this statement

```
        *(pointer+i) = '2';
```

character '2' is assigned to elements of the array so when you will print them you indeed will see character 2 on the console.

```
        printf("%c\n", *(pointer+j));
```

If you want to deal with pointers then for example this loop

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", *(pointer+j));
    }
```

you could rewrite like

```
    for ( char *p = pointer; *p; ++p )
    {
        printf("%c\n", *p);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems:

1. You can't use `strlen()` when the input isn't properly `'\0'`-terminated, and your array isn't. That call gives undefined behavior.
2. Printing the character whose code point is `2` probably makes your terminal behave funnily, since it's not a printable character. You should use `%d` and cast to `(int)`.

Also note that `*(pointer + i)` is *much clearer* if you write it as `pointer[i]`.